# Storing data(string) out of bounds in a dynamically allocated array

Tags: c, string

Following is a very simple C program:

```
char *p = (char*)calloc(5,sizeof(char));
strcpy(p,"Elephant");
printf("String = %s\n", p);
p[6] = 'D';
printf("String = %s\n", p);
```

which allocates a char array of 5 elements using calloc() and uses strcpy() to copy a string into the array. Following is the output:

```
String = Elephant
String = ElephaDt
```

Clearly, I requested for 5 char elements only and hence curious to know why the OS memory mgmt allowed me to store more elements out of the bounds of the dynamically allocated space in **p**. If I was allocated only a space of 5 characters, how did strcpy() was able to store an even bigger string "Elephant" which is greater than 5 characters in length?

Comment: C have no bounds-checking, the compiler will not complain (or really know) if you write out of bounds. Doing that leads to *undefined behavior* though, so don't do it.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg "will not complain ... if you write out of bounds" is defined behavior.  Certainly C does not specify bounds-checking, yet a compiler may employ it.  Writing out of bounds is UB.

Comment: "why the OS memory mgmt allowed me to store more elements out of the bounds of the dynamically allocated space in p."  --> What did you expect the code would be required to do in a situation like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When memory is allocated, this is generally done by a memory manager. These often allocate larger chunks of memory from the OS, and then hand that out to malloc() and friends in smaller parts.

The 5 bytes you allocated are therefore very likely part of a larger chunk of memory. Since you violated the boundaries of your allocation, but not of the larger chunk, the OS does not interfere. It can mean, however, that you corrupted other memory of your own program, by overwriting an allocation nearby. It can even mean you corrupted the data the memory manager uses to keep track of allocated and free memory. But that is not a given. It is simply undefined behaviour.

*Undefined behaviour* does not mean that you must get a runtime error. It can just as well mean that nothing happens, or that you start WW3, or whatever. It is undefined, but it does not necessarily mean a crash.

Answer (score 0):

By using `strcpy()`, [c](/questions/tagged/c) will copy the number of characters you want to the destination you define. It does not check for the bounds of your array. It simply keeps copying until it has copied the whole word.

---

This means that you are allowed to do it without a compile error. However, this invokes [undefined-behavior](/questions/tagged/undefined-behavior) (see [this link](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) to understand it), as you cannot be sure what happens out of the bounds of the allocated memory. In your case nothing bad happened (actually what happened was what you wanted to happen) but you cannot be sure in general.

Answer (score -1):

The array, that you are allocating dynamically, **it's getting allocated from Heap memory**. As @Rudy Velthuis has mentioned, Heap memory is allocated in big chunks. Thus, in normal scenario, your program is running fine. But consider a scenario, where **there's a tight situation and most of your memory of your computer is occupied**. At that time, there's a high probability that memory chunks of one process in heap is residing next to heap chunk, allocated to your process. **And making situation even more probabilistic, assume that your array is getting allocated at the extreme end of the heap, then accessing beyond the end of allocated memory, will make your program to access other program's heap.** **In that case, OS will step in, denies access to your program and your program will crash.**

Hope, it helps you.

Comment: Your program, once compiled, will behave exactly the same in a tight or non-tight memory situation.

Comment: @tofro, I have described a hypothetical scenario. Moreover, I personally experienced the same. Program compiled using turbo compiles, accessing memory beyond boundaries, crashed sometimes and sometimes, it ran fine. I wish I might be able to showcase you that executable.